# Textfields are not appearing at desired position

Tags: html, css

I want to show the text fields to the right side of screen. I have also used the div tags to do so but unable to get the output according to the code. Although the same code is gibing the desired output in my Index page but in my Sign Up page it is not working. Also the button is appearing as "danger button". Here is my code:

```
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Login";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<style>
  div.scroll {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  div.padding {
    padding-top: 8cm;
  }
  div.padding1 {
    padding-left: 6cm;
  }
</style>
<div class="scroll">
  <h1 style="color:#F4981F; font-family:'Segoe Marker'">Sign Up</h1>
  <div class="padding">
    <div class="row">      
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-md-offset-6">
        <div class="container">
          <form action="/Home/Signup1" method="post">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <label style="font-size:x-large; font-family:'Segoe Print'; font- style:italic; font-weight:bolder; color:#F4981F">Username</label>
                  &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                <td><input type="text" name="un" size="30" style="height:30px;font-size:medium; border-color:#F4981F; font-weight:bold; font-family:'Segoe Print'">  <br/><br/><br/>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <label style="font-size:x-large; font-family:'Segoe Print'; font-style:italic; font-weight:bolder; color:#F4981F">Password</label>
                  &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                <td><input type="password" name="pas" size="30" style="height:30px;font-size:medium; border-color:#F4981F; font-weight:bold; font-family:'Segoe Print'"><br /><br />
            </table>
            <div class="padding1">
              <button class="btn btn-larger btn-warning" type="submit" style ="font-family:'Segoe Print'; height:40px; font-size:large; font-weight:bolder">Signup</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>   
  </div>
</div>
```

Remember that the same code is working perfectly fine in Index page but not in another form.

Comment: Maybe adding a link to your version and a drawing of what you want to achieve would clear things up?

Comment: You have invalid HTML all over your code sample (unclosed `<td>` and `<tr>` tags)

Comment: @MarcusMüller my app is running at local host. I want the textfields at the right side of the form. You can say that as that Yahoo mail sign in page. I only want text fields at the position as that of in Yahoo Sign in page.

Comment: @JRulle i corrected my mistake but the issue is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want the sign in controls top right? Check the snippet below. You may want to view it full screen to see it properly.

```css
div.scroll {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
div.padding {
  padding-top: 8cm;
}
div.padding1 {
  padding-left: 6cm;
}
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <h1 style="color:#F4981F; font-family:'Segoe Marker'">Sign Up</h1>
  <div class="padding">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-md-offset-6">
        <div class="container">
          <form action="/Home/Signup1" method="post">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <label style="font-size:x-large; font-family:'Segoe Print'; font- style:italic; font-weight:bolder; color:#F4981F">Username</label>
                  &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="un" size="30" style="height:30px;font-size:medium; border-color:#F4981F; font-weight:bold; font-family:'Segoe Print'">
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <label style="font-size:x-large; font-family:'Segoe Print'; font-style:italic; font-weight:bolder; color:#F4981F">Password</label>
                        &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                        <td>
                          <input type="password" name="pas" size="30" style="height:30px;font-size:medium; border-color:#F4981F; font-weight:bold; font-family:'Segoe Print'">
                          <br />
                          <br />
            </table>
            <div class="padding1">
              <button class="btn btn-larger btn-warning" type="submit" style="font-family:'Segoe Print'; height:40px; font-size:large; font-weight:bolder">Signup</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. But i dont want them to be on the top right. But now atleast they are appearing on the right side. I dont know why my same code is working perfectly fine in Index form and not in another! And the button is not still appearing as danger button.

Comment: i changed the values of top and right in the container tag. The issue of Button is left now.

Comment: Its possible that you have additional css in the second file which overrides the styling in this case. As for the danger button it looks like you have set the Bootstrap class for danger to warning (unless im mistaken) Does the rest of bootstrap build for you?

Comment: yes i have used bootstrap and i have not used any other css in my second file in which it is workinf fine.